# SignalR returns error - but how to find what it means $.connection.hub.error(function (err)

Tags: signalr

The following alert is fired in my app, but JSON.stringify(err) is always "". Is there any way for me to understand what is triggering this exception?

```
            $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
                alert("Error signalR:" + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the built in SignalR debuging to true, then it should give you some additional information in the browser console.

e.g.

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

Also I would use Google Chrome or FireFox when debuging and add the error to the console via:

```
$.connection.hub.error(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note though that this will break the code in other browsers that do not support `console.log();` So you might want to take this a step further and use a custom log function. Take a look at [Paul Irish's `log()` plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/) which gives you a cross browser log function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SignalR 2.2.0 and don't have this problem with the same code as yours and with logging = false.

Alternatively, you can access the error message with:

```
$.connection.hub.lastError
```